# How to declare a Class<?> object such that is is an Enum AND an Interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

I have a utility class that needs to work on a generic Class but must be restricted to those that are an enum and implement a particular interface.

```
// These two work
Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass;
Class<? extends MyInterface> interfaceClass;

// This is what I want but does not work
Class<? extends MyInterface & Enum<?>> enumAndInterfaceClass;
```

For generics I can successfully use this

```
public class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> {
    public MyClass(Class<T> theClass) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However I can't use the Generics everywhere and need to declare it separately. I am not sure if this is even possible.

So my question boils down to how can I declare a member variable with those constraints?

So Currently MyClass is a singleton then as needed the enum/interface can be updated. The return values of its operations will change depending on which enum it is given. I would like to not have the generics on it since that would require creating a new instance for every change to the enum. There is a lot of code using it already so deviating from the singleton is not going to be approved. So a reference must be kept. I suppose I could only enforce the Interface requirement then check in the setter method that it is an enum throwing an exception otherwise but that is not ideal.

**Edit** (Updated question and added more detail)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can only declare **intersection types** (this is what `&` creates) for type parameters of classes and methods. You can not declare a local variable with an intersection type directly; you can create such variables with the aid of a class or method type parameter, as seen in the answer of milkplusvellocet.

See the JLS reference in this answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643378/282229

Comment: 'You can not declare a local variable with an intersection type.' This isn't true, see my answer.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet It should read 'You can not declare a local variable with an intersection type directly'

Comment: Thanks that linked question does help clarify why it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void foo();
}

public final class Utils {

    public static <E extends Enum<E> & MyInterface> void doWork(Class<E> clazz) {
        for(E enumConstant : clazz.getEnumConstants) {
            enumConstant.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I didn't notice your line about using the captured type as  a local variable. You can of course use this throughout the body of the parameterised method, see revised snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think that will work for me. I mistyped local should have been member variable. I have updated my question.

Comment: No problem but I still don't understand what you were asking. 'The return values of its operations will change depending on which enum it is given.' Why couldn't you achieve this using a parameterised `MyClass`?