# Field with multiple generics

Tags: java, generics

Why can't I declare a field with generics that implements multiple interfaces/classes?

```
class MyClass {
    private Class<? extends Enum<?> & Foo> bar;
    //..
}

interface Foo {
  // ...
}

public enum A implements Foo {
   // ...
}
```

Compiler error: `Syntax error on token &`

Comment: `String` is a `final` class, so nothing can `extend` it.

Comment: The compiler error is explicit on this.

Comment: Id does not work with Enum as well

Comment: And if `String` wasn't `final`, you could.

Comment: What would an `Enum<? extends Foo> & Foo` look like?

Comment: Your not extending interfaces. Interfaces are implemented. Your are asking for 2 superclasses, and in Java you can't extend more than 1 class (but you can implement more than 1 interface)

Comment: You've now posted three versions of the declaration, with no indication of why you want to do this or what the compiler error message is. Is this now the question you want to ask? I don't want to put effort into answering it, only for it to change again...

Comment: @Nutel `enum`s are final too.

Comment: @lateralus WRONG. `extends` is used in generic declarations as a specification of class hierarchy.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `Class<? extends Enum<? extends Foo> & Foo>` is equivalent to `Class<Foo>`, if `Foo` is an enum.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i commented one of 3\4 versions he posted with that mistake, he changed lot of versions of the same code

Comment: @lateralus your comment if fundamentally wrong. `extends` in a generic declaration has nothing to do with extending classes versus implementing interfaces.

Comment: Enum is an abstract class

Comment: Did you mean to write `public class Bar<T extends Enum<T>, Foo> { ...` ?  This is perfectly valid Java.

Comment: @John Skeet, I just clarified the question so people are not confused with final classes, because it does not really matter which class/interface is used String/Enum/MyInterface. The use case: I have an enum that implements an interface and I want to make sure that the correct class is used.

Comment: Mostly it's that Java's type system just isn't designed for it, to be perfectly honest.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually, I think it is.  My comment shows how to do it; assuming this is what OP is trying to ask.

Comment: @David Wallace no, I want a field not a class

Comment: So what type are you expecting that field to be?  Sorry, but I'm confused by your use of the word `Class` in the declaration.

Comment: So you do mean `java.lang.Class`?

Answer (score 0):

Question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643378/4112645).

In short, and quoted from the [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9):

4.9 Intersection Types An intersection type takes the form T1 & ... & Tn, n>0, where Ti, 1in, are type expressions. Intersection types arise in the processes of capture conversion (§5.1.10) and type inference (§15.12.2.7). It is not possible to write an intersection type directly as part of a program; no syntax supports this. The values of an intersection type are those objects that are values of all of the types Ti, for 1in.