# Multiple inheritance generics in reference type

Tags: java, generics

Given: A class with a generic Type T which both extends and implements an interface

```
class RescheduableRunnableIntent<T extends Intent & Timmed> implements Runnable{
    IntentManager intentManager;
    T intent;
}
```

How can I specify the same condition for an ArrayList or Hashmap? The following line produces a syntax error

```
private HashSet<? extends Intent & Timmed> set;
```

Comment: What exactly is the usecase? Can you move the generic specification up to the class level?

Comment: A workaround would be to create a class which implements `Intent` and `Timmed` and extend this class in the generic

Comment: I think it's `T extends X & Y1`, not `?`.  You need to actually use a type variable there.  But mostly you  would use `T` for some type that had already been declared.

Comment: I tried to use T instead and any permutation I could think of. As @Oswald suggested creating an abstract class in between solves this issue. I am surprised that there is no way to handle it in another way. The use case is an event system which is supposed to execute tasks (the intents) in a repetitive manner. The delay is not necessarily fixed but may be depended on the day of the week other outside conditions.
Therefore this class wraps 2 runables which will get executed one after another (the task and the rescheduling operation) into another runable.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643378/6413377). It is quite profound explanation about why _there is no way to handle it in another way._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer not to use the type wildcards because they are too restrictive. Say for instance, check this code sample:

```
List<? extends Number> listExtendsNumber = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
Number num = new Integer(1);
listExtendsNumber.add(num); // compile error - you can't add stuff
listExtendsNumber.add(1);   // compile error - you can't add stuff
```

Sometimes you really want to be this restrictive. However, what I found is that people who use bound wildcard types, they usually want something else.

In your you need to figure out whether you want to accept **any** type that extends `Intent` and `Timmed`, or just one particular type?

As far as I can tell, you have the following options:

#### 1. A Wrapper around `Set`

You can specify a wrapper that deals with one particular type:

```
public class TimmedIntentSet<T extends Timmed & Intent> implements Set<T> {


    private Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    // consider defining constructors other than the default

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return set.isEmpty();
    }
    // ... more delegator methods
}
```

This can be quite flexible. Say for instance, consider the following types:

```
public interface Timmed {}
public interface Intent {}
public interface TimmedIntent extends Timmed, Intent {}
public class TimmedIntentClass implements TimmedIntent {}
public class TimmedAndIntent1 implements Timmed, Intent {}
public class TimmedAndIntent2 implements Timmed, Intent {}
```

If you're happy with some type-check warnings, then you can do almost anything with this `TimmedIntentSet`:

```
    TimmedIntentSet tis = new TimmedIntentSet<>(); // warning
    tis.add(new TimmedAndIntent1());  // warning
    tis.add(new TimmedAndIntent2());  // warning
    tis.add(new TimmedIntentClass()); // warning
    tis.add(2);                       // compile error
```

However, if you don't want to `@Suppress` your warnings, then you'll see more than a handful of restrictions:

```
    TimmedIntentSet<TimmedIntentClass> tis = new TimmedIntentSet<>();
    tis.add(new TimmedAndIntent1());  // compile error
    tis.add(new TimmedAndIntent2());  // compile error
    tis.add(new TimmedIntentClass()); // cool
    tis.add(2);                       // compile error
```

#### 2. Add that `Set` to the class where it's used

You can add a Set into the class you've just specified above. This accepts one particular type:

```
class RescheduableRunnableIntent<T extends Intent & Timmed> implements Runnable{
    IntentManager intentManager;
    T intent;
    Set<T> intentMap;
}
```

You can define a new type that's both `Timmed` and `Intent`, but that has other kind of restrictions. Using the same types as above, you can't just add any of the `Timmed` and `Intent` -s to your set:

```
Set<TimmedIntent> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new TimmedAndIntent1());  // compile error
set.add(new TimmedAndIntent2());  // compile error
set.add(new TimmedIntentClass()); // only this is fine
```

#### Wrapping up:

It all boils down to what you want to do? Almost anything is possible, but each choice comes with trade-offs.