# Java subclassing from discrete class and interface?

Tags: java, swing, class-hierarchy

The graph below describes the hierarchy of `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass`. With Java is it possible to define a variable that can hold values that are either `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass`, i.e a variable definition that restricts values to instances that are both sub-classes of `JComponent` and implementations of `MyInterface` so that functions from `JComponent` and `MyInterface` are simultaneously available?

I realize the normal way to do this would be to create an intermediate abstract class that extends `JComponent` and implements `MyInterface`, so I am wondering if this behavior is possible without doing this.

The reason behind the strange class hierarchy is that I initially created `MyAbstractClass` to be used as a generic visual type and now would like to add some features to it, i.e. `MyInterface`, for use in other places. however I will also need to make some new classes that have the same additional features from `MyInterface` but are not instances of MyAbstract class. It would be nice if I didn't have to create a duplicate `MyAbstractClass` that extends some other intermediate class that extends `Jcomponent` and `MyInterface`.

```
o       JComponent
|
|\
| \
|  \
|   o   MyInterface
|   |
|   |\
|   | |
|\  | o MyClass
| | |
| o |   MyAbstractClass
| | |
| | |
| | /
| |/
| |
| o     MyOtherClass
```

Comment: Composition might work better for this rather than inheritance, perhaps via the Command design pattern (which of course uses inheritance, but not at the GUI structural level)

Comment: You could perhaps use generics `<T extends A & B>` I'll have a think.

Comment: @d.j.brown This is currently only allowed for class definitions I just want to define a variable in this way... [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic/6643378) discusses why java doesn't have this option for wildcards

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If I understand what you are suggesting, I don't think it is possible since JComponent is not an interface. If it were, I could create a new interface that extends `JComponent` and `MyInterface` and then sub-class `MyAbstractClass` and have it just implement that new interface. Which would retain all the coded functions from `MyAbstractClass` whilst allowing functions from `MyInterface` to be implemented

Comment: @jdodle will this variable ever change type within the instance of the class holding the association? i.e. will it switch between `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass`?

Comment: I never said anything ab out "possible" but more about what I'd do. I avoid sub-classing GUI components unless necessary, and when I do subclass them, I try to make my GUI classes as "dumb" as possible so that all they do is display the state of the model and transmit the user interactions to the controller, and **that's it**.

Comment: @d.j.brown If I understand what you are asking then I would say no. But to clarify, the variable will strictly be used to call functions from either `JComponent` or `MyInterface` so there will be no need to cast it to any other type. However `MyClass` is really just a placeholder for a variety of classes that would extend `JComponent` and implement `MyInterface`. I was thinking this relationship would be defined for each individual `MyClass` but that isn't strictly necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the variable remains the same type for any given instance you can use an upper-bounded Generic type for the variable and inject the object either via the constructor or mutator method.

Using your heirarchy as an example, below `Foo` has a variable `bar` of type `T` which is bound to be a subtype of `JComponent` and `MyInterface` in this case. Then you can construct an instance of `Foo` defining the concrete type. In practice, you're probably better off defining an abstract subclass of `JComponent` that provides the `MyInterface` methods. This way you wouldn't be bound by the Generic type.

**Foo**

```
public class Foo<T extends JComponent & MyInterface> {

    private T bar;

    public Foo(T bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void fooAction() {
        bar.interfaceMethod(); // MyInterface method
        System.out.println(bar.getWidth()); // JComponent method
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<MyClass> a = new Foo<>(new MyClass());
        Foo<MyOtherClass> b = new Foo<>(new MyOtherClass());
        a.fooAction();
        b.fooAction();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
MyClass
0
MyOtherClass
0
```

The same principle could be applied to static methods, e.g.:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        staticAction(new MyClass());
        staticAction(new MyOtherClass());
    }

    public static <T extends JComponent & MyInterface> void staticAction(T bar) {
        bar.interfaceMethod();
        System.out.println(bar.getWidth());
    }
}
```

---

For completeness, the classes used in this example:

**MyAbstractClass**

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass extends JComponent { }
```

**MyInterface**

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void interfaceMethod();

}
```

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass extends JComponent implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyClass");
    }
}
```

**MyOtherClass**

```
public class MyOtherClass extends MyAbstractClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyOtherClass");
    }
}
```

Comment: This morning I realized that this JComponent/MyInterface value only needs to be stored as a class member so the class can be templatized in this way. Which eliminates the need for the container class `Foo`. Outside of my particular implementation I believe this is a great solution.