# Java interface &

Tags: java, interface

I can't understand what is it??

```
interface A{
    void foo();
}
interface B{
    void foo();
}
```

then what is the result of (A & B)

```
        System.out.println((A & B) () -> {
            System.out.println("1");
            System.out.println("2");
        });
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: It's `Object`, essentially. There's no other common supertype between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for an explanation of [IntersectionType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/IntersectionType.html)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148411/expressing-anonymous-intersection-types-in-java

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It's not a syntax error. The type `A & B` is an intersection type that also happens to be a functional "interface" because `A` and `B`'s `foo`-method has the same signature. The `System.out.println` will just print the `toString` of the lambda-object that is created.

Comment: @marstran didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Indeed [no syntax error here](https://ideone.com/M0DGXC).

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A & B` is an intersection type. An object of this type can act as both an `A` and as a `B`.

This particular intersection type also happens to be a "functional interface" type, which means that it only has 1 abstract method. This lets you instantiate an object of this type using a lambda-expression. `A & B` is a "functional interface" type because both `A` and `B` have the `foo`-method with the exact same type signature.

So that is what this code means. You are instantiating an object of type `A & B`, implementing the `foo`-method with the lambda-function.

```
(A & B) () -> {
  System.out.println("1");
  System.out.println("2");
}
```

The `System.out.println` will just print out this lambda object using it's `toString`-method. Note that it will not call the actual `foo`-method. Your code will therefore just print out something similar to this: `Main$$Lambda$1/1642360923@1376c05c`