# Bounded wildcard as a method parameter

Tags: java, methods, parameters, interface, bounded-wildcard

I would like to create a method which returns type is a map object and parameter should be a class which extends A and implements I.
So my code is as follows:

```
public Map<String,String> getIdea(Class < ? extends A & I) { .....}
```

But i am getting a compilation error saying that my syntax is wrong. It is expecting a comma right after A. It does not work even with comma. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Make the method generic, declare a type parameter with those bounds, then use that parameter as the type argument for the `Class` parameter.

Comment: answer to your question is here:
[see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic)

Answer (score 2):

To put what Sotirios Delimanolis said in comments into code:

```
public <T extends A & I> Map<String, String> getIdea(Class<? extends T> clazz) { }
```

To be honest, I don't think that the wildcard gets you anything here since `T` is tightly bound, so you may be better off with the non-wildcard version.

Comment: I agree. Since `T extends`, and isn't used anywhere else, `? extends T` is redundant and should just be `T`, as in `getIdea(Class<T> clazz)`. Still, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

For parameter to be a class which extends A and implements I, type parameter should be defined at method level as below:

```
public <T extends A & I> Map<String,String> getIdea(T t) { .....}
```