# How to create a collection/list of instances of many classes which implement two common interfaces (without modifying those classes)?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two interfaces (`IfaceA`, `IfaceB`) and two classes implementing those interface (class `C`, class `D`):

```
interface IfaceA {
    void doA();
}

interface IFaceB {
    void doB();
}

class C implements IfaceA, IFaceB {
    public void doA() {}
    public void doB() {}
}

class D implements IfaceA, IFaceB {
    public void doA() {}
    public void doB() {}
}
```

**I cannot change the signature of those classes.**

How can I make a list or collection of instances of classes that implement both interfaces?

What I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<? extends IfaceA & IFaceB> test_1;
    List<? extends IfaceA, IFaceB> test_2;

    Class<? extends IfaceA, IFaceB>[] test_3;
}
```

are all wrong (a wildcard can have only one bound while I'm not sure whether it's possible with type bound).

I know this one might work:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[] {
        new C(), new D()
};

for (Object o: objects) {
    IfaceA a = (IfaceA) o;
    IfaceB b = (IfaceB) o;

    a.doA();
    b.doB();
}
```

but this simply doesn't look right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible way around is creating wrapper type which

- can only wrap instances of classes which `implements IfaceA, IFaceB`
- allows calling all methods from both interfaces on wrapped instance on wrapped instance.

It can look like:

```
class Wrapper<T extends IfaceA & IFaceB> implements IfaceA, IFaceB {

    private final T element;

    public Wrapper(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public void doA() {
        element.doA();
    }

    @Override
    public void doB() {
        element.doB();
    }

}
```

This will let us use that Wrapper as type of elements in the List:

```
class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Wrapper<?> can represent both Wrapper<C> and Wrapper<D>
        List<Wrapper<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Wrapper<>(new C())); 
        list.add(new Wrapper<>(new D()));

        for (Wrapper<?> wrapper : list){
            wrapper.doA(); //both calls compile fine
            wrapper.doB(); //both calls compile fine
        }

    }

}
```

---

#### Alternative version.

Instead of delegating method calls to wrapped element we can access that element via getter and call all methods from IfaceA & IFaceB interfaces directly on it.

```
class Wrapper<T extends IfaceA & IFaceB> {
    private final T element;

    public Wrapper(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Wrapper<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Wrapper<>(new C()));
        list.add(new Wrapper<>(new D()));

        for (Wrapper<?> wrapper : list){
            //here `var` represents "some" subtype of both IfaceA & IFaceB 
            var element = wrapper.getElement();             

            // so following is legal
            element.doA(); 
            element.doB(); 
        }
    }
}
```

OR if someone prefers Java 8 style we can rewrite above loop like

```
list.stream()
    .map(Wrapper::getElement)
    .forEach(element -> {
        element.doA();
        element.doB();
    });
```

Comment: The alternative solution is quite impressive. Nevertheless I think it's a big limitation of the wildcard bound that it cannot extend two interfaces. Thank you, good advices!

Comment: @Benjamin You are welcome. Also agreed, don't know why we can't have `<? extends Type1 & Type2>`. Based on accepted answer in [Why can't you have multiple interfaces in a bounded wildcard generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6643241) it looks like there ware some preparations to allow it. My guess is that since this is not that very common use-case/need (which can be solved by creating another interface which will extend both IfaceA & IFaceB which will allow us to have `List<? extends mixOfAB>`) Java developers probably focused on other things.